# Memory Utilization: WPF vs Windows Forms

Tags: .net, wpf, .net-4.0

A simple sample application that has zero functionality shows a surprising difference in memory utilization.

Numbers are in private bytes and using .NET 4.0.

- WPF - 56MB
- Windows Forms - 13MB

Frameworks are notoriously bad at doing nothing, but I'm still surprised by this difference. Can I expect that an application built with WPF will consume 30-40MB more in private bytes as a cost of using WPF?

Answer (score 6):

From this data, no. What you can deduce is that *an application that does exactly nothing* will consume 43MB more in WPF.

My point being that as more features get used by the application, the difference might increase, decrease, or stay constant. No way to know.

Comment: Empirically, yes that's true. This experiment only proves that WPF as a framework is less good at doing nothing than Windows Forms. I don't really care how well WPF does nothing. It seems though that using WPF has a higher baseline cost in terms of memory than Windows Forms.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you try creating a UI with 10,000 controls in it in WPF, and a similar UI in WinForms, and then check to see what the memory usage is.  It's fairly simple to do this programmatically - just create a Form and add 10,000 `TextBox` objects to its `Controls` collection, for instance.  (Spoiler alert:  you'll need to use a number that's smaller than 10,000 with WinForms.)  This won't give you an especially accurate point of comparison either, but it's a more accurate one than an app that does nothing, and it will teach you a valuable lesson about windowless controls.

Answer (score 0):

WPF (and its basic controls) offer much more features, so increased overhead is to be expected.

The advantage of WPF is that it is more "developer time efficient" (to create rich UIs) than WinForms, not more "memory efficient" or "CPU efficient".

Though since WPF is fully GPU-accelerated, performance gains are to be expected in some cases. But these are not the performance gains you can see in task manager, these become apparent in form of increased animation smoothness and user responsiveness.